# How to properly use git with my simple team structure

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I feel like for my requirements Git is overkill but I have to use it due to company constraints and really don't have time to fully read into how git works...

I have a test automation project that requires me to work on different machines (different domains) and literally just keep both of these locations up to date... there is also a 2nd guy who just wants to keep his local repo up to date but he won't do much work on his own

so no different branches no merge required I just need to keep my REMOTE the single most important and up to date reference and pull the current state to my 2-3 local repos that are in different domains before working on them

So I just want to keep 2 or 3 local repos up to date by pulling the status from remote every time I switch machines but I don't want to mess around with merging because I don't care what the local state is I always work from the remote status
I use tortoise git as this is integrated in the automation software

Which commands will I ever need to work like that? I commit locally on one of the 2 machines and push the latest changes to remote, next time when I have to switch my local machine I want to just FORCEPULL the latest state to local without messing around with any merges or stuff.. just plain overwrite and keep remote my only important state

Additionally it would be best if I could use tortoise for the commands and not the git shell, is this possible with tortoise without firing up the commandline?

Thanks for any help guys!

Comment: How does this relate to GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

If you're only committing and pushing from one machine you won't need to deal with merges.

`git commit -am "MESSAGE"` and `git push` from one machine, and `git pull` from the other machine(s), should be all you need.

I don't understand why you're using TortoiseGit for "automation" since it is a GUI, but there are context menu items for the things you need to use:

`Git Commit -> BRANCH_NAME` appears in the main context menu.

`Push...` and `Pull...` appear at the top of the TortoiseGit specific menu.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of what you're attempting to use git for, you'll need the following commands

1. pull down the repository from your remote:

   - `git clone <remote    location>` (should only need to be done once
     per local machine)
2. commit your local changes:

   - `git add .` (adds files to local staging
     area)
   - `git commit -m "commit message"`
3. push your changes to remote epository:

   - `git push origin master` (assuming you want to push the master branch)
4. update local info about remote repository:

   - `git fetch`
5. force local branch to match remote branch:

   - `git reset --hard origin/master` (this will blow away local changes and force it to match the remote repository)

Do the last two commands in sequence to erase any local changes and pull down the latest remote repository

If there are updates locally and you're trying to do a `git pull`, you might get into a situation where you need to do a merge...